# c++ Why is this true and not false?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand why `! ( ( true || false ) && false )` is `true` and not `false` but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Why do you think it could be true? `X and false` is always false, so `not (X and false)` is always true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
! ( ( true || false ) && false )
```

is equal to

```
! ( ( true ) && false )
```

which is

```
! (  false )
```

which is

```
true
```

Answer (score 4):

```
true || false == true
true && false == false
!false == true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to go through it one-by-one:

`! ( ( true || false ) && false )`

`3 ( (      1        )     2    )`

1) `true || false` => true because it is true if at least either of them is true.

2) `true && false` => false because it is only true if both are true, i.e. if at least either of them is false, it evaluates to false.

3) `!(false)` => true because '!' means negation, the negation of false is true, and the negation of true is false.

Answer (score 0):

For these kind of Boolean logic issues I always try to break it into steps.

So for this the first condition

```
    ( true || false )
```

This is equal to true as you're saying true OR false

The next condition can now be read as

```
   ( true && false )
```

Which is false

The final bit that makes it true as oppssed to false is the !

The final part can be equated to

```
    !( false )
```

The ! flips the value so the final statement is true